# Entity Manager Hibernate / Spring Roo Error - Cannot create TypedQuery

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-roo, jpql

Using Spring Roo (but manually creating these methods so that may be of no relevance) I am trying to display two tables in one list. I have the below method to get all people with their usernames in the class people.java. I believe this method works correctly.

```
public static TypedQuery<Person> findAllPeople() {
  String queryStr = "SELECT o.name, b.username FROM Person o INNER JOIN o.users b";
  TypedQuery<Person> query = entityManager().createQuery(queryStr, Person.class);
  return query;
}
```

Here is the code for the controller

```
@RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
public String list(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Model uiModel) {
    uiModel.addAttribute("people", Person.findAllPeople());
    return "people/list";
}
```

When I try to run this through a list.jspx I get the error "Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [com.test.peopletest.Person]; "

Does anyone know how I can return this query with all the results output properly?

Answer (score 2):

You are not querying for a Person object, you're query appears to return two strings

```
  SELECT o.name, b.username...
```

In order to return a Person, you should have

```
  SELECT o FROM Person o
```

Just from looking at your query, it looks like you can drill down to the users/usernames once you have your person object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can use something like ...

```
SELECT o FROM Person o FETCH JOIN o.users b
```

when you walk the person.users all the users are loaded from memory (no DB round trip) will be done.

Or, theoretically (read untested!!), you could

```
SELECT o.name, b.username FROM Person o FETCH JOIN o.users b
TypedQuery<String[]> query = entityManager().createQuery(queryStr, String[]);
```